# How to use Apache POI ooxml in project?

Tags: maven, apache-poi

Very new to apache and maven as a whole, so there may just be a really obvious answer I'm not finding.

I have added the proper dependencies to my projects but I am unable to actually use any of it. My pom.xml dependencies are as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

In my code, the lines

```
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.*;

...

XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
```

results in the error XMLSlideShow cannot be resolved to a type. What should I do to make it recognize the stuff I added as dependencies?

I've tried importing, deleting and replacing the pom, trying other classes, and nothing seems to work.

Comment: It is `org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow`. So `import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;`.